# DeAuthorize callback URL not working

Tags: facebook, callback

I registered a DeAuthorize callback URL for my Facebook app in the 'advanced settings' tab of my app. Then I removed my app from a test page, the callback URL is not called. Looks like many people have questions about DeAuthorize callback URL.

Could anyone share some hints/clues/suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: I remove the app from a page as suggested in  https://www.facebook.com/help/212515628782291. Checked in apache's log. the URL is not called. Double checked to make sure I had the right URL there. Can someone please give some help? it is so frustrating. Thank you

Comment: me bad. The URL is behind the firewall :(